# Emacs sort-regex-fields

Tags: regex, string, sorting, emacs

I am using emacs 24.5 and trying to sort a file like this:
At first glance it seems to be in sorted, order, but only numerically from "left-to-right" in the sense that the order is `s-199` then `s2`.

```
file '602036248001_4483709143001_s-1.ts'
file '602036248001_4483709143001_s-10.ts'
file '602036248001_4483709143001_s-100.ts'
file '602036248001_4483709143001_s-101.ts'
file '602036248001_4483709143001_s-102.ts'
file '602036248001_4483709143001_s-103.ts'
file '602036248001_4483709143001_s-104.ts'
file '602036248001_4483709143001_s-105.ts'
file '602036248001_4483709143001_s-106.ts'
file '602036248001_4483709143001_s-107.ts'
file '602036248001_4483709143001_s-108.ts'
```

I attempted to use `sort-regexp-fields` in emacs, with the "record" regexp as `file '602036248001_4483709143001_s-[^a-zA-Z]*.ts'` and with the "key" regexp as `[^a-zA-Z' _-]\{1,3\}.ts`

But these seem to highlight matches in `regexp-builder` (which, by the way, why does it require you to wrap your regexp in quotes " "...?)

This doesn't seem to work and I am stumped. I also attempted to use sort-columns to mark a region and sort, which did not work either.

Comment: `sort-regexp-fields` won't work because it can only sort lexicographically, not numerically. However, `sort-numeric-fields` won't work because it assumes fields are delimited by whitespace. And `sort-columns` won't work either; it assumes all your fields are the same length _and_ it sorts lexicographically.

Comment: Maybe you want to look at `sort-numeric-fields`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use awk for this, not Emacs. Try something like

```bash
awk -f sort.awk your-file.txt
```

where `sort.awk` is:

```awk
BEGIN {
    FS = "[-.]"
}
{
    key[NR] = $2+0
    line[$2+0] = $0
}
END {
    asort(key)
    for (i = 1; i <= NR; i++) {
        print line[key[i]]
    }
}
```